# JavaScript function in WebView and ViewPager

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-viewpager

I have a problem with Javascript in WebView. Currently I have a ViewPager, which adds View dynamically when needed. Before add a view to viewpager, I inflate it and load an embedded webview inside:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.notebook_page, null);
        setupWebView(v);
        pagerAdapter.addView(v);
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In the webview, first I load a local html, and then inject a JS fuction to set several input on HTML.

```
    private void setupWebView(View v) {

    myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web_resources/index.html");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(myWebView, url);
            Log.d("WebView Content", "Injecting JS");
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:function('" + input_var + "')");
        }
    });
}
```

Funtion setupWebView is called correctly for every view inflated, however, the JS function does not work properly

The same piece of code works perfectly in an Activity, if there is only 1 page. Just in ViewPager, where there are more than 1 pages to display the webviews, JS only loads in the last page.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: which android version you're using?

Comment: On Android 5.0 the JS never loads. On lower version (4.4 and 4.0) the JS loads at the last page of viewpager.

Comment: Hi. I would like to correct that only the last page in viewpager, webview actually loads JS.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, on 5.0 Android you should use different method to use javascript. I use this snippet of code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');", new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        Log.e("LoginActivity onReceiveValue", s);
                    }
                });
            } else
                webView.postUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');", null);
```

Also, you should include @JavascriptInterface tag on your javascript method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@JavascriptInterface
public void processHTML(final String html) {
//method called from javascript
}
```

Comment: Actually the code works well in an independent activity. I mean if there is only 1 page, then it is fine, but if there are more than one page, in case of Viewpager, it loads only in the last page.

I have edited my quesiton to clarify it